# C: Printing only the last n lines (tail program)

Tags: c

I am doing some programming exercises for C and I am stuck with this problem.

Problem: prints only the last n lines based on the argument that the user inputted

For example: argument 2

User Input: I\nAm\nLearning\nC\nProgramming

```
I
Am
Learning
C
Programming
```

Output: C\nProgramming

```
C
Programming
```

So based on the argument that the user provided which in this case is 2, it should only provide the last 2 line. So far, what I have for now is for the user can input an argument.

Code that I have as of now

```
char input;
char main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
   if(argc == 2) {
     input = *(argv[1]);
     return NULL;
   } else {
     return "Need one argument\n";
   }
}
```

I was thinking of creating a struct to hold the line and also its length. I kinda got the idea of it but I do not know how to implement it in C.

Thank you!

Comment: What  have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Lazar, I updated the post and included what I have right now. Thanks!

Comment: How do you declare `input`? Do you have an idea for parsing it as a number? If the argument is `10`, then `input` will be `'1'`. Do you know how to parse more than a single `char` as a number?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure he meant what you have tried in order to solve that. The code you have does/tries nothing to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Also, `main` is supposed to return an `int`, and neither `NULL` nor `"Need one argument\n"` are supposed to be integers (although based on a couple quirks of how C works, this might compile with warnings). If you're getting these exercises from somewhere, I recommend going a few steps back to Hello World and starting from the beginning.

Comment: Hi @DanielH, I just created a char for it. That's what I have for now.

Comment: @Shaun As I mentioned in my other comment, a `char` can only hold a *single* character, and won't work if the argument is `10`. I really do think you should go back to an earlier exercise, because you seem to have several false assumptions about C which are beyond the scope of this site to fully explain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer will be this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int current_line;
  int from_line;
  char *text;
  int i;

  if (argc < 3) {
    printf("%s\n", "Should provide at lest 2 arguments");
    return 1;
  }

  from_line = atoi(argv[2]);
  text = argv[1];
  current_line = 0;
  i = 0;

  while (text[i++] != '\0');

  while (i >= 0) {
    if (text[i] == '\n') {
      current_line++;
    }
    if (current_line == from_line) {
      break;
    }
    i--;
  }

  /*
    If text is "SOME TEXT" then text + 0 is also "SOME TEXT"
    but text + 1 would be "OME TEXT" and text + 5 "TEXT".
  */
  printf("%s\n", text + i + 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Firstly it will check if the user passed at lest 2 arguments to the program.
Then it will assign `argv[1]` which should hold out text to `char *text` pointer.
Next we will convert `argv[2]` to integer and store it in `int from_line` variable.

Then we have assign `int i` value 0 and run loop to find the size of the string.

We are going to enter the loop so we need to initialize `int current_line`,
it keeps track of the current line we are in.

Then we have the loop, it will run until we reached the end of the string or we found the line we are looking for,
the loop will run though string in reverse (from end to beggining) since we are looking for nth line from the end.

`'\n'` in most programming languages means newline, if we found newline we are going to increment the `current_line` variable.

At the end we need to print the string from the character that precedes `'\n'` newline character.

Comment: That prints starting at line `n` but the exercise is to orint the last `n` lines. If you really feel like doing OP's homework for them, you should probably try to respect the problem description.

Answer (score -1):

Because of my badge count, i couldn't write a comment so i want to post my answer.Hope this will help...

```js
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

 char First[1024],Second[1024];
 //Type zero when want to exit from loop

 int flag = 1;
 while(flag){
  scanf("%s",&First);
  scanf("%s",&Second);
  printf("enter 0 to exit\n");
  cin>>flag;
 }

 printf("%s  %s",First,Second);
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ouch, C++ as an answer to a C question, using conio.h at that.

Comment: Please don't format your code using the JavaScript snippet button. This code isn't JavaScript.

Comment: So what if the argument is not two?

Comment: `scanf("%s",...);` fails to read a _line_ of input - it loses all white space.  Fails on long text.  `&` in `scanf("%s",&First);` makes for the wrong type and technical undefined behavior.